# Retrieve tagged photos from Instagrams API without forcing user to login?

Tags: instagram-api

I want to retrieve a list of recent photos with a given tag to display on a website in a very simple gallery.

For that, the [doc](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) says I need an access token. However, it seems that the only way to authenticate against [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) is through OAuth; which involves sending the user to instagram and allowing my application access to their basic data. However, I don't want my users to do anything; I'd like my application to authenticate against Instagram for me and then retrieve the data I want.

Sounds simple, but all online documentation seems to end up in "Redirect your user to...". And I find no sensible ways to do this programatically; it's all about sending users away, letting them authenticate, and then receiving the access token afterwards. I *could* of course scrape the HTML, parse the forms (for example, the unique-per-session `csrfmiddlewaretoken` field which needs to be posted along with login requests etc) and let my server side application pretend to be my own user and login/authorize the app, but that doesn't seem like *the way to go*.

I could also just authenticate manually in the browser, pick up the auth token and paste into my application; but as the doc says: "do not assume your access_token is valid forever." - so I'd like this to be fully automated.

If I try to create a `WebClient` and POST to `https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&response_type=code&scope=basic` it just returns a *403 Forbidden* which is of no use. (For what it's worth, I'm using C# and have found [instasharp](http://instasharp.org), but this problem is not tied to any given platform...)

Am I completely overlooking something, or am I right that server side authentication against Instagram has become really complicated? Most other social media platform API's I've touched lets me get some form of authentication token just by posting a combination of the application id and secret.